# MySQL : How to know which table that record belongs to in UNION result

Tags: mysql, field, union, record, belongs-to

Lets say that I want to get the records from 2 table by using UNION.
How could I add a field to each record that would tell me which table it belongs to? It just something like this :

```
id     |    title     | link            | table
-----------------------------------------------------
1      | Title 1      | somelink.html   | articles1
2      | Title 2      | link2   .html   | articles2
3      | Title 3      | link3   .html   | articles1
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select some_column, 'union_1' as from_where
from table1
union 
select some_column, 'union_2' as from_where
from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 'Table1' TableSource
FROm Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, 'Table2' TableSource
FROm Table2
```

This will work/make sense for `UNION ALL`, but might be misleading if you use `UNION`, as duplicates will then be included due to the differentiating source column.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in your UNION, like:

```
SELECT *, 'articles1' AS table_name FROM articles1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'articles2' AS table_name FROM articles2
```